# How to run Apache Gobblin inside a container?

Tags: java, gradle, hadoop, gobblin

I'm trying to run Gobblin inside a docker container but there don't seem to be any tags on `apache/gobblin` on dockerhub so if I try to use that image it's failing on pull.

I've tried building an image myself using the `Dockerfile` in the gobblin repo on github but when I run that image it's failing due to some `log4j`/`slf4j` error listed below

```
gobblin-standalone-1  | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContextFactory.isClassLoaderDependent()Z
gobblin-standalone-1  |     at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:49)
gobblin-standalone-1  |     at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
gobblin-standalone-1  |     at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
gobblin-standalone-1  |     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
gobblin-standalone-1  |     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
gobblin-standalone-1  |     at org.apache.gobblin.runtime.app.ServiceBasedAppLauncher.<clinit>(ServiceBasedAppLauncher.java:91)
```

which is probably caused by this

```
gobblin-standalone-1  | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
gobblin-standalone-1  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/gobblin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
gobblin-standalone-1  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/gobblin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
gobblin-standalone-1  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/gobblin/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

I tried to exclude those packages but it doesn't seem to be working since I get exactly the same error on the new image aswell

```
configurations.all {
    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    exclude module: 'slf4j-reload4j'
}
```

Comment: 1) Whats failing to pull? 2) The error is saying you're missing log4j2 classes. The other two you're trying to exclude are log4j1.x